# How to use Multiple return in c#

Tags: c#

I am quite new in C#. I am wondering if it possible to have many returns in a code. 
My code is not working at the moment. See below:

```
public static int GeometryandControlPoints(int t, double rinn, double rout, int nx, int ny, int poly)
{
    int nel, n, m, ncp, gdof;
    nel = nx * ny;
    n = nx + poly;
    m = ny + poly;
    ncp = n * m;
    gdof = 2* ncp;
    return (nel, n, m, ncp, gdof);
}
```

The error is on the `return` line as seen in the image below.

[image]

Comment: You must declare the list of return types. Like `public static (int nel, int n, int m, int ncp, int gdof) Geometry...(...)`

Comment: Your return type is in should be (int , int (and so on)) read about tuples here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. Post actual code into the question. Sometimes in order to help, someone will copy and paste your code into Visual Studio so they can work with it. They can't do that with a picture. And it means that the question isn't self-contained. Someone should be able to see the question - with its code - and the answer, all on one page.

Comment: It is also very helpful to explain what your goal is [as well as what you are doing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). There may be a more efficient or idiomatic way of accomplishing your goal.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Filip, you can return multiple ints by using a [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-5?view=netframework-4.8):

```
public static Tuple<int, int, int, int, int> GeometryandControlPoints(int t, double rinn, double rout, int nx, int ny, int poly)
{
    int nel, n, m, ncp, gdof;
    nel = nx * ny;
    n = nx + poly;
    m = ny + poly;
    ncp = n * m;
    gdof = 2 * ncp;
    return new Tuple<int, int, int, int, int>(nel,n, m, ncp, gdof);
}
```

A different approach would be to create a custom **CLASS** that encapsulates the five ints and return that instead.

Comment: `Tuple` is a class.  It's just a generic one, rather than a custom one written for a more specific purpose.